ingress & custom hostname
I've started studying k8s but I have some issues making all work locally, I have 2 apps (node+nextjs) + 1 db (pg), the db is served by docker (I connect to it using host.docker.internal) while the 2 apps are docker images.
The k8s is very simple: 2 services + 2 deployments + 1 ingress, this is the ingress file:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffers-number: "4"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "16k"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: local.api.my-app.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-api
                port:
                  number: 4001
    - host: local.my-app.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-frontend
                port:
                  number: 3000

local.my-app.com is the nextjs and it is sending requests to the api http://local.api.my-app.com both server side & client side, in my /etc/hosts I've added:
127.0.0.1 local.api.my-app.com
127.0.0.1 local.my-app.com

the problem is that when the nextjs app send a request to local.api.my-app.com (server side) I get this error:
      code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 80

I suppose because in the /etc/hosts this hostname is pointing to localhost instead of host.minikube.internal, but at the same time when sending request on client side I send the requests to the custom hostname, how can I fix this issue?
Previously I was using path instead of the domain in the ingress and all was working fine

did you map port 80 to your cluster?

Yes, indeed using the oath instead of the hostname all works fine

Do you control the my-app.com domain?  In its DNS, what does the A or AAAA record for local.my-app.com point to?  If you have a local setup and you don't control this domain, you might find it easier to remove the host: lines from the Ingress configuration and use path-based routing instead.

I control the DNS but atm I'm just playing locally, with paths it works fine but when I'll push this online I'll use hostnames, so I wanted to have something working with the hostname locally

I assume you need access from the outside to both of the hostnames.
Recommendation:
You should consider using in cluster DNS to discover each of the applications internally in the cluster instead of hard coding in the /etc/hosts files in each of the pods.
Your nextjs service -> service-frontend..svc.cluster.local
Your API service -> service-api..svc.cluster.local
The ingress controller/resource is usually meant to be only used for outside access (outside cluster)
